# Unable to copy complete folder from remote server to local machine using powershell

Tags: windows, powershell, scripting

I'm trying to copy folder from remote server(Windows 2016) to local machine using powershell command. But after copying set of files, I'm getting write error. When I compare folder between remote server and local machine, I see a lot of sub folders and files were not copied to local machine. I'm using below command

```
copy-item -path \\d$\Runtime* -destination "C:\Test\Runtime\" -Recurse
```

Error I get is:

> CategoryInfo : WriteError: (PasswordCredent...ranslator.class:FileInfo) [Copy-Item], DirectoryNotFoundException
>   FullyQualifiedErrorId :  CopyDirectoryInfoItemIOError,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.CopyItemCommand

**I'm copying complete folder and not a specific sub folder or file. So, above error doesn't make any sense to me. Any help?**

Comment: Are you also using `-Credential` in the argument list?

Comment: no. I'm not. I'm executing the same exact command which i mentioned in earlier post.

Comment: I would recommend using `robocopy` instead.

Comment: You're using a wildcard in your `-Path` argument.  Try utilizing the `-Container` parameter.

Comment: @Bill_Stewart robocopy only copies files which are only modified. Correct me if that is not the case

Comment: Robocopy copies whatever you tell it to.

Comment: It's not hard to find out how `robocopy` works. The `robocopy /?` command and a quick web search should tell you all you need to know.

Comment: robocopy also failed to copy set of files and sub directories from remote server. So, i zipped the entire directory and copied that zip file from remote server to my local machine. Hope this helps for someone.